# Pourquoi n'y a-t-il plus de traces du Prix de l'Humour Noir depuis 2013 ?

Tags: littérature, humour

Le Prix de l'Humour Noir, décerné depuis 1954 est documenté sur ces deux sites :

- [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prix_de_l%27Humour_noir)
- [http://www.bertrandbeyern.fr/](https://www.bertrandbeyern.fr/spip.php?rubrique60)

À la fois Wikipédia et le site de M. Beyern ne mentionnent pas les lauréats après 2013. Le prix a-t-il disparu ? Si oui, pourquoi cette disparition ? Si non, qui sont les lauréats depuis 2013 ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with French language

Comment: @LaurentS. Indeed, I hesitated asking it, however, I didn't find any better adapted StackExchange website, do you know one?

Comment: Definitely not, but SE isn't supposed to answer each and every question in the world... If you don't find any SE site suited for such a question, then you shouldn't be asking it on SE..

Comment: @LaurentS. Understood, I'm voting too then

Comment: Thank you for your understanding, and feel free to come here and ask questions about French language :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Voici un élément de réponse, l'entretien de Bertrand Beyern (président du jury du Grand Prix de l’humour noir) pour le journal "lesinrockuptibles":
https://www.lesinrocks.com/2014/01/08/actualite/actualite/lhumour-noir-ricanement-existentiel-que-lorphelin-de-dieu-inflige-par-represailles-aux-valeurs-des-autres/
Tiré de l'article voilà peut être quelques éléments de réponse:

> Pourquoi est-ce plus difficile qu'hier de trouver une perle ?
>   Il y a un conformisme assez grand.

Ou cet autre exemple:

> L'humour noir se raréfie ?
>
> Nous ne sommes plus dans un monde qui rit, qui sourit. C'est surement
>   lié à l'individualisme, aux techniques. Chacun peut s'isoler, choisir
>   sa chaîne, sa musique, cela fait qu'on est pas forcément attentif à ce
>   qui se passe autour. C'est là qu'on se rend compte que l'humour noir
>   est en train de déserter. Est-ce à cause des nouveaux médias où toutes
>   les paroles se valent ? Ajoutez-y la "déculturation" et la
>   méconnaissance de la langue. L'humour noir n'est plus sur scène car
>   l'ambition des jeunes comiques c'est de devenir chroniqueurs à la
>   télé. On n'en peut plus des sketchs qui commencent par “je ne sais pas
>   si vous avez remarqué mais…”

https://www.numerama.com/magazine/28220-quand-le-csa-bannit-une-grande-partie-de-l-humour-noir.html.

En gros, une chape de plomb est tombée sur l'humour français. Ce que l'on pouvait faire encore dans les années 90,on ne peut plus le faire aujourd'hui.

J'espère t'avoir aidé.